# FFMPEG Amix filter volume is not constant

Tags: audio, filter, ffmpeg, command

I'm having an issue with FFMPEG and amix filter. Turns out that the volume ins't constant, the generated audio starts with a lower volume and after each mixed sound ends the volume is higher and higher. I'm having a headache right now hahaha.

I'm adding the sounds over base.mp3 that is input 0.

Thank's!

Here's an example of a command line:

```
ffmpeg -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/audio/base.mp3
       -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/audio/n7.mp3
       -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/audio/n7.mp3
       -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/audio/n7.mp3
       -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/audio/n7.mp3
       -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/audio/n7.mp3
-filter_complex
 "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono,atrim=end=30[tud0];
 [tud0]volume=1[aud0];
  [1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono,atrim=end=0.944[bud1];
 [bud1]adelay=1544[aud1];
 [2:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono,atrim=end=0.215[bud2];
 [bud2]adelay=2488[aud2];
 [3:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono,atrim=end=0.2[bud3];
 [bud3]adelay=2703[aud3];
 [4:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono,atrim=end=0.209[bud4];
 [bud4]adelay=2903[aud4];
 [5:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono[bud5];
 [bud5]adelay=3112[aud5];
 [aud0][aud1][aud2][aud3][aud4][aud5]amix=inputs=6:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm"
-map 0:a -c:a libmp3lame /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/public/server/temp/c685db3c87e801d049d13d702d9a0ddd.mp3
```

Comment: Does it happen without the dynaudnorm? Which ffmpeg version?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, that was one of the things that I try looking for a solution.

Comment: Anyone with some ideas for this? I can be happy with just a name of the solution haha. Thanks!

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35509147/1407491

Comment: put this, amix=inputs=2:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm - 2 is the length of audio