# ffmpeg mix 20 audio streams without making it quieter

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to mix about 20 audio streams with ffmpeg amix, however as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration), amix has a weired way of making the input streams quieter the more of them you mix together:

> "amix scales each input's volume by 1/n where n = no. of active inputs. This is evaluated for each audio frame. So when an input drops out, the volume of the remaining inputs is scaled by a smaller amount, hence their volumes increase"

How can I get rid of this anoying behaviour?
I just want the audio streams to keep the same loudness, since only one of them has actual audio in it at any give time anyway..

At the moment I end up with a file that is about 1/20 the loudness of the original, making it effectively unusable.

Comment: Like my answer says,you have to renormalize the result using one of the filters listed there.

Comment: Tried both, ended up with the same result: Audio was super quiet.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the volume of each stream by multiplying by n (20 in your case)

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume

Comment: So i would just use multiple "-af" after each -i? e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af 'volume=2' -i input2.mp3 -af 'volume=2'`?

Comment: If that works, yeah. You may have to explicitly switch to floating point to avoid clipping, if the input sound is sufficiently loud to start with. Float is the default, but you never can tell. And then you may want to step up to double if you find that you're losing enough precision to affect the sound quality. See also the volume specification syntax in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/769168/ffmpeg-mixing-and-setting-each-volume-of-a-multi-audio-track-file

Comment: You might also try just multiplying by 20 after the mix (so long as the intermediary file maintains enough precision -- by using float or double for example)