# FFMPEG set volume in amix

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to mix an audio mp3 with a video mp4 while retaining the mp4 audio. This is working with .

```
ffmpeg -y  -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3
 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[out]" 
 -map 0:v -map [out] output.mp4
```

I'm now trying to adjust the volumes of the sound files (video 0.5, audio 1) as part of the mix.

I've been trying things like

```
ffmpeg  -i 020c276b-face-4bb3-9169-e8969c1232ba.mp4 -i test.mp3 -filter_complex 
 "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1]; 
  [1:a]aformat=sample_fmts fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2]; 
  [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]"-map 1:v -map [out]
  -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2  output2.mp4`
```

And I get errors such as

> [Parsed_aformat_2 @ 037f8620] Error parsing sample format: sample_fmts
>   fltp. [AVFilterGraph @ 038be620] Error initializing filter 'aformat'
>   with args 'sample
>   _fmts fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument

Does anyone know how to make the code I've code above that is working, also change the volume of the inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I've tried that. It's for mixing audio, doesn't say anything about video. I get this error [AVFilterGraph @ 04f289a0] The following filters could not choose their formats:
 Parsed_amerge_2
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error configuring complex filters.
Error number -5 occurred

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use `amix` I would suggest using it like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.8[a0]; \
[1:a]volume=0.8[a1]; \
[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4 ;
```

For the `amerge` method:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a0]; \
[1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a1]; \
[a0][a1]amerge,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3 [a]" \
-map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 -shortest output.mp4 ;
```

*Something to keep in mind per comments from [Mulvya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/mulvya):*

> `amerge` terminates with the shortest input (always) and `amix`
>   terminates with the longest input, by default. So the former will
>   always truncate when streams are of different length.

<sub>*`-y` flag omitted for testing purposes.*</sub>

Comment: *Output from both methods should result in files that are identical (or very close)* --> no. `amix` scales each input. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779/5726027

Comment: @Mulvya: I think you might've misunderstood what I meant. In this particular example the methods are doing essentially the same thing -- the resulting file is likely identical; maybe check the hashes. If there were more inputs and dropouts used you would definitely see a difference, yes.

Comment: Even with two inputs, if one is shorter, you will get a difference.

Comment: @Mulvya: What do you mean "shorter"?

Comment: One stream is 10 seconds and the other, say, 9 seconds.

Comment: amerge terminates with the shortest input (always) and amix terminates with the longest input, by default. So the former will always truncate when streams are of different length.

Comment: @Mulvya: Ah, that makes total sense; explained that way puts it in a clear perspective! I've added that information to the answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer worked https://superuser.com/questions/715254/the-following-filters-could-not-choose-their-formats-parsed-amerge-5-consider-i

```
> ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i  video.mp4 -filter_complex
> "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a1];
> [1:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.8[a2];
> [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]" -map 1:v -map
> "[out]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 -shortest output.mp4
```

Tho it did throw a few errors that didn't seem to stop it

> frame=   93 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     642kB time=00:00:03.78 bitra
>   frame=  224 fps=224 q=-1.0 size=    1595kB time=00:00:09.28 bitra
>   Error while decoding stream #1:1: Error number -12 occurred
>       Last message repeated 158 times frame=  274 fps=182 q=-1.0 size=    2382kB time=00:00:11.35 bitra Error while decoding stream #1:1: Error
>   number -12 occurred

Comment: I'd be leery of those errors... I'll put an example using amix for you.