# FFMpeg amix filter volume changes. Explanation request

Tags: ffmpeg

First, the question:
IS THERE somewhere documented or explained how ***ffmpeg amix filter changes the volume*** in the mixed audio files? I couldn't find any good reference.

There are several threads regarding this "issue" that the amix filter changes the volume of the input files. I played around with these and I just cannot explain what is going on. It makes a difference if you "mix" files like concatenate them at specific times or you overlap audio tracks and volume changes just doesn't make any sense.

Firstly, I don't understand WHY the volumes need to be changed.

Some related refs:

- [FFMPEG amix filter volume issue with inputs of different duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration/)
- [FFMPEG set volume in amix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712868/ffmpeg-set-volume-in-amix)

Comment: The first para of my answer in your first link has an explanation. As to why, in order to prevent clipping.

Comment: The link is to explain the loudnorm filter. I still don't get it why is it to prevent clipping? If I open the tracks in audacity, you see the volumes(0 - 100), then you put them together, you want them to stay the same. Still, amix changes the volumes. Another way would be to use one track as "volume" reference or smth similar.

Comment: I explain how amix changes volume. loudnorm, mentioned later, is a suggestion for how to compensate. Suppose you mix two files with floating point samples (0-1), and if one file has a sample 0.7 at time=0.5 and other file has sample 0.8 at that time, then result is 1.5 which can't be represented so it will be clipped and stored as 1. So amix scales inputs before mixing.