# How can I play audio file(.mp3, .flac, .wav) and then loop over it (mix every few seconds) another audio file(wav) using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I got two different commands.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=end=10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[begin];[0:a]atrim=start=10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[end];[begin][1:a][end]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" output
```

This command inserts second.mp3 into input.mp3. It seems to always keep the parameters of input.mp3. It inserts it in exact 10 seconds of input.mp3.

Here is the second command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=10000|10000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix=duration:first" output
```

This command is closer to my final goal. It plays input.mp3 and in exact 10 seconds it plays along second.mp3 without stopping input.mp3's sound.(I think that's called mixing?)

My final goal is to create final.mp3.

Its duration must always equal input.mp3 duration. It must keep the samplerate, the count of channels, etc of input.mp3

When playing final.mp3, it must play the whole input.mp3.
But each 10-15 seconds, it must play second.mp3 without stopping input.mp3.(mix)
It could be said that I must use "Second command" but in a loop.
It would be great if there is one-line command for that in ffmpeg.
I am working with flac, mp3 and wav and both of the commands were suitable for that.

For example:

input.mp3 could be 40 seconds long.

second.mp3 could be 2 seconds long.

When I play final.mp3 it will be 40 seconds long, but each 10-15 seconds(on random) it will play second.mp3 at the same time as input.mp3.

Sadly I have no experience with ffmpeg, both of the commands I got are answers to questions here in stackoverflow. Hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edned up, generating long ffmpeg code using php

```
-i input_mp3.mp3 -i second.wav -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=2000|2000[1a];[1:a]adelay=19000|19000[2a];[1:a]adelay=34000|34000[3a];[1:a]adelay=51000|51000[4a];[1:a]adelay=62000|62000[5a];[1:a]adelay=72000|72000[6a];[1:a]adelay=85000|85000[7a];[1:a]adelay=95000|95000[8a];[1:a]adelay=106000|106000[9a];[1:a]adelay=123000|123000[10a];[1:a]adelay=139000|139000[11a];[1:a]adelay=154000|154000[12a];[1:a]adelay=170000|170000[13a];[1:a]adelay=184000|184000[14a];[1:a]adelay=197000|197000[15a];[1:a]adelay=212000|212000[16a];[1:a]adelay=224000|224000[17a];[1:a]adelay=234000|234000[18a];[1:a]adelay=248000|248000[19a];[1:a]adelay=262000|262000[20a];[1:a]adelay=272000|272000[21a];[1:a]adelay=288000|288000[22a];[0:a][1a][2a][3a][4a][5a][6a][7a][8a][9a][10a][11a][12a][13a][14a][15a][16a][17a][18a][19a][20a][21a][22a]amix=23:duration=first,dynaudnorm" output_mp3_dynaudnorm.mp3

-i input_wav.wav -i second.wav -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=1000|1000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix=2:duration=first,dynaudnorm" output_wav_dynaudnorm.wav

-i input_flac.flac -i second.wav -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=1000|1000[1a];[1:a]adelay=11000|11000[2a];[1:a]adelay=27000|27000[3a];[0:a][1a][2a][3a]amix=4:duration=first,dynaudnorm" output_flac_dynaudnorm.flac
```

Those kind of syntax seems to work. Also I added dynaudnorm to negate the negative effect of amix([FFMPEG amix filter volume issue with inputs of different duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration/38714779#38714779))
Even thought it is claimed that dynaudnorm fixes the problem of amix, it is not completely true, at least not in my case, where I am using it ~30 times...

But the final command works. I will ask a new question how to improve the results.

Comment: Try adjusting the `f` and `g` option values for dynaudnorm.