# FFMPEG mixing two stereo files code question

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg code:

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -stream_loop -1 -i "%~2" -i "%~1" -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest" -f wav "%~3n"
```

I want to generate a wav stereo file from two wav stereo input files. It seems to work but what does this part of the code exactely?

```
[0:0][1:0]
```

Thank you for your help. It seems like the volume of one of the input files is a little bit reduced?

Comment: does https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1 answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0:0][1:0]` means first input to the filter is taken from file index 0, stream 0, and second input to the filter is taken from file index 1, stream 0. See [answers](https://superuser.com/q/1345175/) here for an explanation.

amix will [reduce volume of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779) during mix. Add `volume=2` after amix to restore it.