# Reduce volume when the watermark playing using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm using the `createWaterMark` method to create an audio watermark that play 3 times, the `injectWaterMark` inject the created watermark into the **original audio** file, everything works fine, but I would like to reduce the volume of the **original audi**o file when the watermark start playing.

```
 public static String createWaterMark(String inputPath, String outputPath, int duration) {
        return "-y -i " + inputPath + " -af apad -t " + duration / 3 + " " + outputPath;
    }

    public static String injectWaterMark(String inputPath, String waterMarkPath, String outputPath) {
        return "-y -i " + inputPath + " -filter_complex amovie=" + waterMarkPath + ":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[beep];[0][beep]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2 " + outputPath;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG amix filter volume issue with inputs of different duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration)

Comment: @OrangeDog thank you, let me check it out

Comment: Or this? [How to change volume of audio at specific time in audio](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/24076)