# Merging multiple audios to a video with ffmpeg causes the volume being reduced. How to avoid that?

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, video-processing

```js
        const command = ffmpeg();

        const mp4Path = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'temp', `q-video-${new Date().getTime()}.mp4`);

        fs.writeFileSync(mp4Path, videoBuff);
        console.log('mp4 file created at: ', mp4Path);

        // Set the video stream as the input for ffmpeg
        command.input(mp4Path);

        const mp3Paths = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
            const audio = audios[i];
            const mp3Path = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'temp', `q-audio-${new Date().getTime()}-${i}.mp3`);
            mp3Paths.push(mp3Path);

            fs.writeFileSync(mp3Path, audio.questionBuf);
            console.log('mp3 file created at: ', mp3Path);
            // Set the audio stream as the input for ffmpeg
            command.input(mp3Path);
        }

        // -------
        // ChatGPT take 1
        const audioTags = [];
        const audioFilters = audios.map((audio, index) => {
            const startTime = audio.start_at; // Replace with your logic to calculate start time
            const endTime = audio.end_at;     // Replace with your logic to calculate end time
            audioTags.push(`[delayed${index}]`);
            // Working
            // return `[${index + 1}:a]atrim=start=0:end=${(endTime - startTime) / 1000},adelay=${startTime}[delayed${index}]`;
            return `[${index + 1}:a]dynaudnorm=p=0.9:m=100:s=5,atrim=start=0:end=${(endTime - startTime) / 1000},adelay=${startTime}[delayed${index}]`;
        });
        
        // Concatenate the delayed audio streams
        const concatFilter = audioFilters.join(';');
        
        // Mix the concatenated audio streams
        const mixFilter = `${concatFilter};[0:a]${audioTags.join('')}amix=inputs=${audios.length + 1}:duration=first:dropout_transition=2[out]`;

        // Set the complex filter for ffmpeg
        command.complexFilter([mixFilter]);

        // Set the output size
        if (!isScreen) {
            command.videoFilter('scale=720:-1');
        }
        else {
            command.videoFilter('scale=1920:-1');
        }

        // Set input options
        command.inputOptions([
            '-analyzeduration 20M',
            '-probesize 100M'
        ]);

        // Set output options
        command.outputOptions([
            '-c:v libx264', // Specify a video codec
            '-c:a aac',
            '-map 0:v',      // Map the video stream from the first input
            '-map [out]'     // Map the audio stream from the complex filter
        ]);

        // Set the output format
        command.toFormat('mp4');

        // Set the output file path
        command.output(outputFilePath);

        // Event handling
        command
            .on('start', commandLine => {
                console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
            })
            .on('codecData', data => {
                console.log('Input is ' + data.audio + ' audio ' +
                'with ' + data.video + ' video');
            })
            .on('progress', progress => {
                // console.log('progress: ', progress);
                console.log(`Processing: ${
                    progress.percent ?
                    progress.percent.toFixed(2)
                    :
                    '0.00'
                }% done`);
            })
            .on('stderr', stderrLine => {
                console.log('Stderr output: ' + stderrLine);
            })
            .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.error('Error merging streams:', err);
                console.error('ffmpeg stdout:', stdout);
                console.error('ffmpeg stderr:', stderr);
                reject(err);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('Merging finished successfully.');
                const file = fs.readFileSync(outputFilePath);
                console.log('File read successfully.');
                setTimeout(() => {
                    fs.unlinkSync(outputFilePath);
                    console.log('Output file deleted successfully.');
                    fs.unlinkSync(mp4Path);
                    console.log('MP4 file deleted successfully.');
                    console.log('mp3Paths: ', mp3Paths);
                    for (let mp3Path of mp3Paths) {
                        fs.unlinkSync(mp3Path);
                    }
                    console.log('MP3 file deleted successfully.');
                    if (isScreen) {
                        for (let path of pathsScreen) {
                            fs.unlinkSync(path);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        for (let path of pathsCamera) {
                            fs.unlinkSync(path);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('All temp files deleted successfully.');
                }, 3000);
                resolve(file);
            });
        
        // Run the command
        command.run();
```

This is how I am merging my video files (which is an array of webm files) right now. It seems this command is causing the volume of the video gradually increase from the beginning to the end (the earlier part of the video has much lower volume than later part of the video). How should I fix this?

Things tried and investigated so far:

- I have checked the original video, it does not have the volume issue. So the volume issue was caused by this piece of code without an doubt.
- I have tried dynaudnorm, not fully understanding how it works, though. Adding it to each of the audio file does not fix this issue, and adding it as a separated filter at the end of the combined filter string would break the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ffmpeg v4.4 or later, add `normalize=0` as an option to `amix`. You can skip `dynaudnorm`.

See this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779/) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running another ffmpeg command for the video generated by this command in the question with `dynaudnorm`, which actually works and solved my issue. So it seems there's no way to run it inside the merging function in order to make it work as expected.